# Compact Lie groups are rational homotopy equivalent to a product of spheres

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups

According to [1] and [2], it is “well-known” that a compact Lie group $G$ has the same rational homology, and according to [2] is even rational homotopy equivalent, to the product $\mathbb{S}^{2m_1+1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}^{2m_r+1}$ of spheres of dimensions $2m_i+1$ where $m_1,\ldots,m_r$ are the exponents of (the Weyl group of) $G$.

Where might I find a proof, and ideally, a discussion with more background, of this “well-known” fact?  (Something like a textbook or survey article would be best, and I would be content with the statement at the homology level.)

**PS:** Implicit in my question is the fact that the $m_i$ above are the same $m_i$ that appear in the analysis of the Weyl group of $G$ as a reflection group (see, e.g., [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Reflection_group)).  But possibly there is need for two completely different references, one to describe the rational homology type of $G$ as a product of spheres of dimension $2m_i+1$ and another to relate the $m_i$ to the exponents of the Weyl group.

1. Macdonald, [“The Volume of a Compact Lie Group”](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01392542), *Invent. Math.* **56** (1980) 93–95.
2. Hashimoto, [“On Macdonald's formula for the volume of a compact Lie group”](https://ems.press/journals/cmh/articles/215), *Comment. Math. Helv.* **72** (1997) 660–662.

Comment: The statement about the homology (with its Pontrjagin product) / the cohomology (as a Hopf algebra) is in many references.  There is a nice survey by Pierre Cartier that also includes some of the history: https://preprints.ihes.fr/2006/M/M-06-40.pdf  One good source for the topology of Lie groups and their homogeneous spaces is "Topology of transitive transformation groups" by Onishchik.  The statement about the homotopy groups follows from Examples 10 and 11 in Chapter 7.  I believe Becker-Gottlieb, "The transfer map and fiber bundles", has the statement about products of spheres.

Comment: The statement is not in Becker-Gottlieb, but I found the original reference in an article of J.-P. Serre, namely Corollaire 1 of Section 3 of "Groupes d'Homotopie Et Classes de Groupes Abeliens": https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Serre-Classes.pdf

Comment: "rationally homotopy equivalent" sounds better English.

Comment: The argument connecting the cohomology Hopf algebra of $G$ to the fundamental invariants under the Weyl group action on $\mathbb{Q}[X^*(K)] = Sym^\bullet(H^2(K;\mathbb{Q}))$ for a maximal torus $K$ is in Borel's survey article where he discusses his proof that the cohomology algebra of $G/K$ equals the quotient of $\mathbb{Q}[X^*(K)]$ by the ideal generated by the fundamental invariants, "Topology of Lie groups and characteristic classes": https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1955-61-05/S0002-9904-1955-09936-1/S0002-9904-1955-09936-1.pdf

Comment: By the way, I am teaching all of this stuff this semester.  I have a few other relevant links on the course webpage: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jstarr/M552s22/index.html

Comment: Compact Lie groups are particular cases of finite H-spaces.  Modulo some technicalities in the rational homotopy theory, the statement follows from Lemma 8.4.2 of  https://joshuamoerman.nl/docs/15msc-rational-homotopy-theory.pdf